# What's the easiest way to get the result of an HTTP GET request in using URL in JRuby

Tags: java, jruby, tropo

I'm attempting to build a [Tropo](http://tropo.com) Ruby application and I need to retrieve the result of an HTTPS GET. The Tropo platform doesn't have the httpclient Ruby gem so I can't use that. The Ruby engine used is JRuby so a suggestion has been to make use of the Java [URL](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class to do the request. I've played around with it a little bit and I seem to be able to create the URL object ok but am now struggling with how to get the results of executing the request. How do I do it?

```
javaURL = java.net.URL.new svcURL
transferResult = javaURL.getContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what getContent() does exactly, but you can use openStream() which gives you an InputStream to read from.

```
javaURL = java.net.URL.new svcURL
transfer = javaURL.openStream()
// read from stream
transfer.close()
```